# Error 10 - ionic 3(Cordova) cordova-plugin-googleplus After install from Google Play Store

Tags: cordova, ionic3, google-plus-signin

I followed all the steps to publish apk on play store. But getting error 10 after installing from play store.
But When I install released apk from my computer to android mobile it is working fine.

**Steps followed to create apk -**

**Step 1:** Created build release ionic Cordova project using below command -

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

After this i got unsigned apk("../../platforms/android/build/outputs/android-release-unsigned.apk").

**Step 2:** I signed the apk using java keytool command -

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ../../release-key.keystore ../../platforms/android/build/outputs/android-release-unsigned.apk keystore-alias
```

**Step 3:** Also verified the signature by using java tool -

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs ../../platforms/android/build/outputs/android-release-unsigned.apk
```

Got a messag in command window "Signature verified".

**Step 4:** Then used zipalign tool of "Android SDK" to align/optimize the apk, command is as below -

```
        zipalign -v 4 ../../platforms/android/build/outputs/android-release-unsigned.apk ../../platforms/android/build/outputs/ToDo.apk
```

**Step 5:** Published the apk to "https://play.google.com".

After Some couple of hours published apk was listed on Google PlayStore.
I installed it from Google PlayStore on my android mobile and getting error 10.

**Steps followed to get SHA-1 Key -**

**Step 1:** Keystore file is created using java keytool command -

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ../release-HMC.keystore -alias release-key -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

**Step 2:** Got SHA-1 Key by using below command -

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ../release-HMC.keystore -alias release-key
```

**Step 3:** Enabled the Google Sign-in from "https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin"

**And I also enabled "Google+ API" on Google Console("https://console.developers.google.com/apis/").**

**What i did wrong please Help !**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that the google play app signing was selected by default when we publish.

**1**. Open Google Play Console(https://play.google.com/apps) and log in with your credentials then select your android app.

**2**. Goto Your App management.

**3**. Goto "Release Management" menu and select "App Signing"

**4**. In "App Signing" you will see the "App Signing Certificate" Panel Copy "SHA-1 certificate fingerprint".

**5**. Goto "https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin" to create the Android mobile project.

**Note:** In "Step 5" create project form asks you to select project so, for this you need to create project first on " https://console.developers.google.cm/".

**6**. Create the Android mobile project from "step 5". In above step, it asks for "SHA-1 key"(paste SHA-1 certificate fingerprint which you get from Google Play Console) to create the project.

**7**. After "step 5" and "step 6" Google automatically creates the "OAuth Client" and API key for you in your "https://console.developers.google.com/" project.

**8**. To access your Google API services get OAuth and API Key for your android project from "htts://console.developers.google.com/"

[image]

For more information see the link - "http://www.jomendez.com/2017/08/30/ionic-2-google-sign-in-error-10-with-firebase/"

Comment: Thanks. I feel into this confusion as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally got the soloution:**

Go to the Google console developers site:

There are 2 clientId there, this is come when you have configure your project and choose the device type to Android. **If you are using Android clientId for your requestId token then that was the mistake**. Now, change your clientId to use Web application instead of Android.